# Establish radius of convergence by ratio test

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, convergence-divergence, frobenius-method

I was able to solve the following :

$(1-x^2)y''-2xy'+\lambda y = 0$ where $\lambda$ is a real constant.

The solution that I obtained is of the form 
$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}C_nx^n$ with

$C_{n+2} = \frac{n(n+1)-\lambda}{(n+2)(n+1)}C_n$

Which gives me:

$y_1(x) = C_0[1-\frac{\lambda}{2}x^2+\frac{(2)(2+1)-\lambda}{(4)(3)}x^4...]$

For the even part and:

$y_2(x) = C_1[x+\frac{2-\lambda}{(3)(2)}x^3+...]$

for the odd one.

I am now required to establish the ratio of convergence using the ratio test, but I can not find a way to do it with my solution written in that form.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the even and odd part as power series in $u=x^2$, $$y=y_e(x^2)+xy_o(x^2),~\text{ where }~ y_e(u)=\sum_kC_{2k}u^k,~~ y_o(u)=\sum_kC_{2k+1}u^k,$$ and compute the radius of convergence for $y_e$ and $y_o$ separately. The minimum of the radii is then the radius for the sum of both parts.

Comment: Sorry I don't think I follow how do i need to re write the 2 series? also what do you mean by the The minimum is then the radius for the sum of both?

Comment: Sorry, was too fast and used $y$ for a new variable while it is already a function in the problem. Added some formulas for more clarity. The application of the quotient rule for the parts should be trivial with the established recursion formula.

Comment: Ok I think I get it, should $y_o(u) = \sum{C_{2k+1}u^{k+1}}  $ though?

Comment: $y$ can be  a polynomial if $\lambda=n(n+1)$ for some $n\in \Bbb N.$ For example $\lambda =2, C_0=0,C_1=1$ and $ y=x $.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet i know that if $\lambda = n(n+1) $ is the legandre equation, i am just looking for a more general solution here.

Comment: The factorization is $x^{2k+1}=x(x^2)^k$, thus $u^k$.

Comment: @LutzL what I don't understand is that doing the radius in that way, there is no dependence on $\lambda$, the radius would be the same for any set of even and odd functions.

Comment: Yes, you get that the radius is $1$ which is to be expected as the singularities of the ODE are at $x=\pm 1$. Why should there be a dependence on $λ$? Compare with the binomial series for $(1+x)^a$, this also has convergence radius $1$ independent of $a$ with the special case of natural integer $a$.